# Resize image after loading

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to load an image from an url and then use it. How can I set the loaded image to `100x150` inside `onload()`?

```js
var img = new Image();
var theurl = "furits/lychee.png";
img.onload = function() {
  //how can I set 100 width and 150 height?
  //do something from resized image
};
img.src = theurl;
```

Comment: `this.width=100;this.height=150;`?

Comment: Are you trying to resize it or crop it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/oykpuq5y/2/):

```js
var img = new Image();
var theurl = 'http://www.sunhome.ru/UsersGallery/wallpapers/78/gomer-simpson-kartinka.jpg';
img.onload = function() {
    this.width = 100;
    this.height = 150;
    document.body.appendChild(this);
};
img.src = theurl;
```

Comment: is it also possible to do `img.height = 150;` and width `auto` as in a css?

Comment: @Bekki simply remove line with `width`: http://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/oykpuq5y/3/.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway you can also use 'img' instead of 'this', since they refer same.

In JavaScript this always refers to the “owner” of the function we're executing, or rather, to the object that a function is a method of.

```js
var img = new Image();
var theurl = 'http://www.sunhome.ru/UsersGallery/wallpapers/78/gomer-simpson-kartinka.jpg';
img.onload = function() {
    img.width = 100;
    img.height = 150;
    document.body.appendChild(this);
};
img.src = theurl;
```

But it should not be used in this case where we are not sure of where the 'this' belongs to.

```
function doSomething() {
   this.style.color = '#cc0000';
}
```

Here, 'this' belongs to the page or 'window' in other words.

Better to use it only while writing OO Javascript / Constructor Functions.